# How to "force" YouTube to AutoBuffer the whole video?

Tags: youtube, video-streaming, streaming, video-download

I have very fast internet, but it gets interrupted a lot (or so it seems with YouTube specifically), and even if it is smooth, I get bugged when I want to skip to a later certain point of the video and it has to buffer allover again.

My only solution is to be able to buffer the whole video before watching it (instead of buffering only the next few seconds) which is also a problem by itself because there is no such option with YouTube!! It seems they care only for the slow-internet people (or more honestly, their servers).

I am a premium user and that irritates me big time.

I've tried some of the solutions offered to previous similar questions here but they are all dated Tapermonkey scripts that don't work anymore.

Anyone has a solution that works actually?